# jquery not firing on similar instances

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $( "#datepicker input" ).datepicker();
        });
```

watching a form field in html. I call a form using Django, and only one instance of the form shows the jquery datepicker. The form fields have the same class, name, id, and are both formatted properly as input fields.

Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

EDIT:
For more clarification. The forms were being called from separate pages.

SOLVED:
There was a condition in the html that only loaded the JQuery library depending the form returned, that is where the problem was. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The id selector will return the first element with the given id... so if you have more than 1 element with a given id then the above solution won't work... use a class instead of id for grouping similar elements... **Becase ID of an element must be UNIQUE**

Comment: @ArunPJohny He's selecting multiple `input` elements within a single `id` selector. There is no duplicate id.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but of they are under different elements all with the id `datepicker` then?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Hmmm. Seems we need to see the OP's HTML to know for sure.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes we need to

Comment: The forms were on different pages.

Answer (score 1):

There should only be a single instance of an ID on a page. You can't have multiple #datepicker on one page.

Comment: Having said that, Rory has probably hit the nail on the head!

Comment: No Rory's answer is not true. If this showed a solution in code instead of describing the problem I would +1 it.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would write code to demonstrate this. Its not a code issue, its page structure. Use classes instead of id's, or match on some attribute of the element. Or, as others have pointed out, there might be one #datepicker with mulitple inputs as children, in which case I'm wrong...

Comment: like this: **jQuery** `$( ".datepicker input" ).datepicker();` **HTML** `<div class="datepicker"><input name="somedate" /></div><div class="datepicker"><input name="somedate2" /></div>`

Answer (score 1):

id selector gets first element in matched DOM. Thus, this only works for first element.You should use class selector instead of id selector.

```
  $( ".datepicker input" ).datepicker();//use class selector instead of id selector
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must not use same id for multiple elements in HTML code, this will cause to failure of jQuery with id selector.

In your case, use class to identify all datepicker inputs.

Example - use `class="datepickerInput"` to all your inputs for datepicker and then call below jQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $(".datepickerInput").datepicker();
        });
</script>
```